# restricting file uploads by size or filetype not working

Tags: php, file, upload, restrictions

I have a PHP script which uploads an image file, and it works fine. But I want to restrict it by size and type, and I can't get the restrictions to work:

```
if ($_FILES["file"]["size"] > 10240) {
    die("Invalid file");
}
```

I thought should trap for all files over 10kB, but it seems to be completely ignored. And this:

```
$allowedExts = array("gif", "jpeg", "jpg", "png");
$temp = explode(".", $_FILES["file"]["name"]);
$extension = end($temp);

if (($_FILES["file"]["size"] != "image/gif")
and ($_FILES["file"]["size"] != "image/jpeg")
and ($_FILES["file"]["size"] != "image/jpg")
and ($_FILES["file"]["size"] != "image/pjpeg")
and ($_FILES["file"]["size"] != "image/x-png")
and ($_FILES["file"]["size"] != "image/png")
and !in_array($extension, $allowedExts))
{
    die("Invalid file");
}
```

Always gives the "Invalid file" message even if it's an allowed filetype & extension.

Both lots of code come originally from `w3schools.com`, but I've changed them to be "not equal" instead of "equal".

Any thoughts on what I'm doing wrong gratefully received.

The form looks like this:

```
<form action="upload_image4.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  <input type="hidden" name="recid" value="<?php echo $recid; ?>" />
  Upload image: <input type="file" name="new_image" />
  <input type="submit" name="action" value="Upload" />
</form>
```

Comment: Rules: 1. Dont ever use `die()` It is dangerous. 2. `$_FILES["file"]["size"]` gives file size in `bytes` 3. Use `$ext = pathinfo($path, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);` to get file extension. 4. You need `$_FILES["file"]["type"]` and not `$_FILES["file"]["size"]`.

Comment: you are comparing file size with the image mime types. your call should be `$_FILES["file"]["type"]`

Comment: Why are you checking file size for the mime type?

Comment: Why has my question been edited? The 'always' was deliberately lower-case because it was the middle of a sentence. And what's wrong with 'cheers'?

Comment: good question, it should be type, not size, I typed it wrongly. It is correct in the actual code. :)

Comment: 1, Okay, but that isn't the reason it doesn't work. It also doesn't work when I was echoing a message....

Comment: 2, yes I know. So 10240 bytes is 10kB, isn't it?...

Comment: Can we see your `<form>` ?

Comment: Why did you change the original code anyway?

Comment: I've added the <form> to the original question.

Comment: I changed the original code because (1) I wanted to differentiate between invalid sizes and types, so I could issue error messages, and (2) because I prefer to have a short error section followed by the valid processing section, which is invariably longer.

Comment: ... also as a rule, I prefer to do the error checking first, not last.

Answer (score 0):

```
$allowedExts = array("gif", "jpeg", "jpg", "png");
$temp = explode(".", $_FILES["file"]["name"]);
$extension = end($temp);

if ((($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/gif")
|| ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/jpeg")
|| ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/jpg")
|| ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/pjpeg")
|| ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/x-png")
|| ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/png"))
&& ($_FILES["file"]["size"] < 10240)
&& in_array($extension, $allowedExts)) {
  if ($_FILES["file"]["error"] > 0) {
    echo "Return Code: " . $_FILES["file"]["error"] . "<br>";
  } 
  else {
    //do something with the image
  }
}
else {
  echo "Invalid image";
  if ($_FILES["file"]["size"] >= 10240) {
    echo "Max filesize is 10kb.";
  }
}
```

This works fine for me.

Comment: The reason I wanted to change it round is that I wanted to issue a different message for invalid size to invalid type. But I guess I can still do that in this structure. Trouble is it becomes very unwieldy, because "do something with the image" is quite a lot of statements.

Comment: ...But I'm going to have a go with it now.

Comment: I have the statement at the bottom for the filesize.  And I understand that you have a lot of different statements for the do something, but that's going to happen regardless.

Comment: I just tried this code without changing a thing, and it doesn't tell me if the file is too big, only if its type is invalid. All I get is the "Invalid image". I suppose, once I get it working, I can change it so that variables are set, instead of actions taken, and then I can test for the variables afterwards.

Comment: Sorry, make sure you replace `$_FILES["image"]` with `$_FILES['file']` as you use in your example.  I've updated my answer.

Comment: Just curious, why are you checking for the filesize twice? And if the 'Return Code' message is an error message, how/why is it different from the the one at the bottom?

Comment: I check at the bottom just for the specific error message to let the user know their file was too large.  Return Code is from the server on the file upload, doesn't have anything to do with your PHP script I don't think.  (ie if the image doesn't upload all the way)

Comment: And I'm only checking again if we get 'Invalid Image'.

Comment: Thanks. I tried it again, with 'file' instead of 'image', and I still get no size error message for an 11kB file.